# Convert "object.property" to "object[property]" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, split

Say I've got strings like `"object.property.property"` and I'd like to be able to use those strings to dynamically create form fields for those properties; I'd need to convert them to `"object[property][property]"`.

I was trying something along the lines of: `"object.property.property".split('.')`

Which of course leaves me with an array: `["object", "property", "property"]`

But I'm unsure how to rejoin them so the properties are surrounded by brackets (`"object[property][property]"`). I tried using `join`, but as far as I can tell that only lets you specify the seperator between each element in the array.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the answers everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an option

```
result, *sub_str = "object.property.property".split('.')
result += sub_str.map{|property| "[#{property}]"}.join
#=> "object[property][property]"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"object.property.property".gsub('.', '][').sub('][', '[') << ']'
```

or, less productive, but more readable:

```
arr = "object.property.property".split('.')
[arr.shift, *arr.map { |e| "[#{e}]" }].join
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the beauty of ruby:

```
obj, *props = "object.property.property".split('.')
obj   #=> "object"
props #=> ["property", "property"]

"#{obj}[#{props.join('][')}]"
#=> "object[property][property]"
```

Update: to also cover objects without properties:

```
def form_name(property)
  obj, *props = property.split('.')
  "#{obj}[#{props.join('][')}]"
  props.any? ? "#{obj}[#{props.join('][')}]" : obj
end

form_name "object.property.property"
#=> "object[property][property]"
form_name "object"
#=> "object"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
"object.property.property".gsub(/\.([\w\d_]+[^\.])/, "[#{$1}]")
```

Though this is only readable to someone who understands `Regular Expressions` well.

Comment: Why would `my_name` and `name1` be considered an invalid property name? Use `\w+` instead of `[A-Za-z]+`.